# Parsing using For in String jsonString = await _ChieseAsset();

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Yo ,, during my experience of flutter i'll try to show on map marker saved into Json file..in this way i retrive only one of row

```
           Future<chiese> loadChiese() async {
            await wait(5);
             String jsonString = await _ChieseAsset();
              final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);

           for ( var i=0; i < 5; i++ ){
            print(i);
           return new chiese.fromJson(jsonResponse[i]);
           }
          }
```

Unfortunally var i show only 0 value and don't scan into json retrive only first value
why???

if i use ...

```
           Future<chiese> loadChiese() async {
           await wait(5);
           String jsonString = await _ChieseAsset();
           final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
           return new chiese.fromJson(jsonResponse);
             }
```

Reciving error ... 
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map'

Any idea??? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
return new chiese.fromJson(jsonResponse);
```

Into this:

```
return new chiese.fromJson(jsonResponse[0]);
```

Comment: Peter thanks for answer i did but 0 collect only One row of json ..i'll want to increase 0 Vector ...